# SOLID & EventAggregator

Tags: .net, events, prism, solid-principles, eventaggregator

I'm trying to follow SOLID as much as I can and I'm facing the following problem while working in a Prism application:

I have a class that handles all the events the module receives from other modules. As the class has two responsibilities (registering the handlers and handling the events) I decided to split the class in two which leads me to make event handlers public (which seems weird anyway).

What do you prefer in this situation, to have two responsibilities in one class or to have event handlers public (or anything else that I'm missing)?

Regards.

**EDIT:**

```
public class Handler
{
    public void MethodHandlingAggregatedEvent()
    {
    }
}

public class Register
{
    .... 

    public void RegisterHandler()
    {
        this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<XXX>().Subscribe(this.handler.MethodHandlingAggregatedEvent);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get why you need to make the event handlers public. Maybe you can provide some pseudo-code?

Comment: @jnovo: if you register the event outside the class handling the event  you need to create a delegate of that method outside of the class thus the method needs to be public. Added code to represent the problem.

Answer (score 3):

To explain my answer better, consider the following example:

- A Prism application contains `ModuleX` and `ModuleY`
- `EventA` and `EventB` are defined somewhere where both modules can access them.
- `ModuleX` contains event handlers for both events.
- `ModuleY` fires these events.

Also consider the following aspects of `SOLID` (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29#Overview))

> **Single responsibility principle**: 
>   a class should have only a single responsibility (i.e. only one
>   potential change in the software's specification should be able to
>   affect the specification of the class)
>
> **Interface segregation principle**: “many client-specific interfaces are better than one general-purpose interface.”[4]

Requirements for the functionality you describe when mapped to this example would be:

1. Register Handler for event A
2. Register Handler for event B
3. Handle Event A
4. Handle Event B

If you have a single class that handles both A and B you would be breaking the Single responsibility principle. If you register an event handler with a handler defined in the same class you would be also breaking the single responsibility principle.

So what now? Splitting up everything would yield four classes, since these apparently are all different responsibilities. According to Wikipedia the SOLID principle exists to simplifiy extending and modifying existing code; therefore it should be there to make your life easier, not harder.

If we create four classes we are forced to open up the event handler code to a scope outside of the class it was created in. In my humble opinion it would be a better choice to keep the event handling code as well as the registration in the smallest scope possible:

```
class MyHandler
{
    public MyHandler(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        eventAggregator.GetEvent<EventA>().Register(HandleEventA);
    }

    private void HandleEventA(EventArgs args)
    {

    }
}
```

`MyHandler` is now responsible for handling `EventA`. Even though it is also registering the handler; one might still consider this as being part of the event handler.

Comment: I understand your point but you know, life is easier when you don't make exceptions, otherwise each time you apply the rule you have to consider if in this case is ok to apply the rule or not ... anyway I get what you mean. I normally take SOLID as my personal bible :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your design is mostly ok.

1. Your class `Register` is responsible for event-handler mapping
2. Each handler is responsible for handle concrete events

I would recommend to rename method `RegisterHandler()` to `RegisterHandlers()` to reflect it's behavior. Also make all classes implementing interfaces. So you can mock them in unit test like that:

```
_registerMock.Verify(x => x.RegisterHandlers(), Times.Once);

_eventAggregator.Invoke(SomeEvent);
_someHandler.Verify(x => x.MethodHandlingAggregatedEvent(), Times.Once);
```